# How to save trained ARIMA model to use later

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, arima

I am using a univariate time series dataset to forecast. I am using ARIMA model to train. But it is a time-consuming process to train every time. Is there any process to save the trained ARIMA model and use it later for prediction?

Here I am giving the [github link](https://github.com/atifkarim/Time-Series-Forecasting-of-a-Power-Plant/blob/master/forecasting_with_ARIMA.ipynb) of the code that I have tried. I am inspired by [this post](https://towardsdatascience.com/forecasting-exchange-rates-using-arima-in-python-f032f313fc56). Below, I am giving the function of the ARIMA model and the necessary line of code.

```
Actual = [x for x in train_set]
Predictions = list()

def StartARIMAForecasting(Actual, P, D, Q):
    print('from function screaming')
    model = ARIMA(Actual, order=(P, D, Q))
    model_fit = model.fit(disp=0)
#     save_model=model_fit.save('model_22.pkl')
    prediction = model_fit.forecast()[0]
#    save_model=model_fit.save('model_22.pkl')
    return prediction,save_model

for timepoint in range(len(test_set)):
    print('I am in for loop')
    ActualValue =  test_set[timepoint]
    #forcast value
    Prediction,save_model_1 = StartARIMAForecasting(Actual, 2,1,2) 
    print('Actual=%f, Predicted=%f' % (ActualValue, Prediction))
    #add it in the list
    Predictions.append(Prediction)
    Actual.append(ActualValue)
```

Here, I want to save the model and then after loading the model I want to do the prediction using my **test data**.

**My assumption is --**
after saving the model I will load it and then will follow the following steps

```
loaded = ARIMAResults.load('model_arima.pkl')

#don't know how and in which line to create this model_arima.pkl

start_index = len(Actual)
end_index = start_index + len(test_set)-1
forecast = loaded.predict(start=start_index, end=end_index)

from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
Error = mean_squared_error(test_set, forecast)
print(Error)
```

Comment: What is wrong with using the .save(...) method that you have commented out?